# How can play mp3 when click on image between <p> </p> tag (html5 code)

Tags: javascript, html, audio

In web source I used, when drafting, everything I wrote (by using CKeditor 3.2) is between `<p></p>` tag, I can't play mp3 by js. I need to play mp3 (also on mobile device). Formerly, I used `<object ... width="20" height="20" >` to play mp3, but it does not work in mobile devices. 
I need to play mp3 file both in PC and mobile device, and I just drafted in `<p> </p>` tag. Somehow for me to play mp3 when click on image ( put between `<p>` tag) or how to edit this code to make it `width=20, heigh=20`

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: Is the problem related to a specific browser?

Comment: Have you tried any JS code ?

Comment: What is keeping you from playing it with JavaScript on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Try labeling the audio tag with an id, hide the audio player, then attach an onclick event to the

tag which contains the image.

sample javascript:

```
var audioTagged = document.getElementById('audioID');
    audioTagged.src = 'audio.mp3';
    audioTagged.load();
```

sample html:

```
<p onclick="triggerAudio()"><img src="smiley.jpg" /></p>
```